# How to change a single input value instead of bulk?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a list of items, each item has one checkbox and one text input box. When the checkbox is checked, I want to set this item's `menu_order_input` value to 0.

```
 jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
       $(document).on('change','input[type="checkbox"][name^="gal-item"]',
       function(){
           $('.menu_order_input').val(0);
 });
```

With the above code, when one checkbox is checked, all items `menu_order_input` value got set to 0. How can I get this function to change one item's value only?

**[edit]**
The `menu_order_input` is wrapped inside a div, the checkbox is without any wrapper. it's inserted into the html before the `menu_order` div by JavaScript.

Comment: You have to select the `.menu_order_input` that is related to the changed checkbox, not all of them. How this is to be done depends on your HTML markup, which only *you* know atm ;) However, jQuery has fantastic documentation, I recommend to read through the traversal methods: http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 0):

it depnends on your HTML markup.

if they're both in a table row, for example you can use `$(this).closest('tr').find('menu_order_input').val(0);`

or if the input immediately follows the checkbox, then use:
`$(this).next('.menu_order_item').val(0);`

or any of numerous other functions from [jQuery: Traversing the DOM](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).siblings('.menu_order_input').val(0);
```